# Consultar usuario de una relación en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy tratando de consultar el usuario de una relación en **laravel** para mi autenticación.

Este es mi modelo y su migración de usuario

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  public function AlumnoUser(){

    return $this->hasOne(Alumno::class, 'id', 'id');
  }
}

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('n_control')->unique();;
        $table->string('rol');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Este es mi modelo y su migración de alumno

```
class Alumno extends Model
{
   public function UserAlumno(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'id');
  }
}

class CreateAlumnosTable extends Migration
{
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('alumnos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id_alumno');
        $table->string('nombre', 250);
        $table->string('apellidos', 250);
        $table->string('carrera', 250);
        $table->string('semestre', 50);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('alumnos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Lo que necesito es consultar el nombre del alumno mediante el usuario para mostrar como usuario logueado, utilizo el siguiente código para llamarlo pero me sale error

```
<span>{{ Auth::user()->AlumnoUser()->nombre }}</span>
```

no se, si este escribiendo algo mal en la consulta

Lo que busco aqui es poder consultar al usuario logueado y un atributo de la tabla a la que le manda la llave foranea EJ. mediante el usuario obtener el nombre del alumno y mostrarlo en el balde con un

```
 <span>{{ Auth::user()->AlumnoUser()->nombre }}</span>
```

o algo parecido a eso pero traerlo mediante la relación en el blade

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que tus relaciones son incorrectas, ¿un alumno cuantos usuarios puede tener?

Comment: que tal, así?¿ con hasOne

Comment: Una consulta... Todos los usuarios son alumnos? o hay también usuarios profesores por ejemplo

Comment: Si personal y admin son tipos de acceso de usuario, entonces el diagrama me parece plantea una solución errónea, pues esos son roles y deberían estar concentrados en una tabla, posterior existir tal vez la de alumnos y por último la de la de users donde se almacena la llave foránea que identifica al alumno y la llave foránea que identifica el rol que tiene

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tenías mal las relaciones tal cual las habías definido.

Parto de que si un alumno puede tener un usuario asociado, entonces en el modelo `Alumno` tu método debe ser así:

Modelo Alumno.php donde un **alumno puede tener solo un usuario asociado**

```
class Alumno extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
         return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
}
```

Posterior en tu modelo `User.php` debes tener una relación de pertenencia a través de `belongsTo()`, donde **un usuario solo puede pertenecer a un alumno**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function alumno()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Alumno::class);
    }
}
```

Además de eso en tu migración de `users` te hace falta la llave foránea que vincule a dicha tabla con la de `alumnos` de esta forma:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('alumno_id');
$table->foreign('alumno_id')->references('id')->on('alumnos');
```

Ahora si necesitas consultar el nombre del alumno por medio del usuario que utilizó para loguearse debería alcanzar con:

```
$usuarioLogueado = auth()->id;

$datosUsuarioLogueado = Alumno::with('user')->findOrFail($usuarioLogueado);
```

- Obtenemos primero el id del usuario logueado por medio del helper `auth`
- Haciendo uso de `eager loading` cargamos al modelo alumno con sus relaciones del método `user`
- Filtramos los resultados con `findOrFail` pasàndole el id recuperado del usuario que inició sesión
- Por cierto yo dejaría las llaves foráneas solo como `id` quitando algún prefijo que pudiera existir

Comment: pero tendría conflicto, por si un alumno solo debe tener una cuenta, pero yo tengo mas tablas que se relacionan con usuario, entonces si le mando llave foranea a user, seria un error

Comment: @EdgarRodriguezTesta no veo por que el conflicot, esta relación solo es entre alumno y usuario, si posterior necesitas relacionar estas con otras tablas puedes hacerlo, la relación aquñi mostrada solo busca cumplir lo que buscas

Comment: considero que seria conflicto porque en user tendria que llamar la llave foranea de alumno, admin, personal y se supone que yo tenia user para mandar la llave foranea de user a admin, alumno y personal y de este modo llamar los datos en el login mostrar el nombre del usuario logueado mediante la relacion

Comment: @EdgarRodriguezTesta no es nada claro lo que tratas de hacer, lo mejor que te puedo recomendar en este caso es que edites y seas por favor tan claro como sea posible, pues entre tus comentarios aqui y la pregunta planteada hay mucha diferencia

Comment: puse un pequeño diagrama para ver si puede ayudar un poco mas